# Unable to update database to match the current model ... But only on one of two apps

Tags: entity-framework

I have two apps that are sharing the same EF Model/SQL DB. This morning, one of the two apps started giving me this message: `Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled`

It's odd because:

1. When I run `add-migration [name]`; the migration file shows no updates needed.
2. The other app works without any issues using the same database. So I know the database and model aren't out of sync.
3. Rolling the app back before the latest deployment does not solve the issue.
4. Both apps work in test without any issues.

I temporarily renamed '__MigrationHistory' to see what was going on, and the app was attempting to recreate tables that where created years ago: `There is already an object named '[table name]' in the database.`

EDIT: I did not delete the files in the Migration folder, so that explains the above results.

Any idea what is going on? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted several other workarounds to no avail.
It was bizarre, my server said the object and db synced, my other apps said they synced, and when I deployed the app on a new server they synced.

I'm just marking this up as a bad Azure server.